# How to search by field first letter?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following query:

```
db.pmusers.find({'firstName':'Arnold', 'lastName':/^z*/ })
```

I want to find documents where firstname equals `Arnold` and lastName starts from `Z`

But this query returns:

```
{"firstName" :"Arnold", "lastName" : "tpxjzqi"}
```

Please correct my query

Comment: @Neil Lunn, I had read it. And I use sintax like in response

Comment: But the problem here is that `*` means **zero or n times**. Zero match means "match anything". So there will be another duplicate, but the question has indeed been asked before. Takes me a moment to find it. Simply `/^z/` works as expected and it's the `*` that is the problem.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, Ok thanks